# Scheme - using `this` as argument of a lambda function?

Tags: oop, scheme, this

Could someone please clarify the concepts behind this use of the "this" keyword?

```
(define call
  (lambda (obj method-name . args)
    (apply (obj method-name) obj args)))
(define -cuboid-
  (lambda (w l h)
    (define volume
      (lambda (this)
        (* h (call this 'area))))
    (define area
      (lambda (this)
        (* w l)))
    (lambda (method-name)
      (cond
        ((eq? 'volume method-name) volume)
        ((eq? 'area method-name) area)
        (else (error "method not found: ~s" method-name)))) 
(define r1 (-cuboid- 2 3 4))
(call r1 'area) ;=> 6
(call r1 'volume) ;=> 24
```

I understand that `this` is a keyword to refer to the object that is being used. I found out that `this` alone doesn't have any particular meaning in this program (it needs to refer to the arguments of the lambda functions).

The call is `((-cuboid- 2 3 4) 'volume)`, which brings to `(* h (call this 'area))`, where has `this` been defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is simply the argument of the `lambda`, this could be anything; try changing it to, e.g., `myself` in the first lambda and `me` in the second (where it is not used, by the way, but needs to be there for the `call` to work).

The call to `((-cuboid- 2 3 4) 'volume)` returns that procedure, with names bound according to the sketch below:

In `call`, `r1 'volume` calls the "lookup method" of `-cuboid-` and returns the `volume` procedure, which is then called with the `obj` argument, binding that to the name `this`

Thus, `this` gets bound to the `r1` argument to `call`

[image: binding sketch]

Comment: so, in the end it's: apply `((-cuboid- 2 3 4) 'volume) (-cuboid- 2 3 4))` wich runs `(* h (apply (-cuboid- 2 3 4) 'area))` which runs `(* h (* w l))`. and why `area` needs an argument, is it a requisite of `apply` that lambdas have at least an argument?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.
 Note that `this` in `volume` is only used to call `area`, but not for finding `h`(which is in the closure of the procedure). A bit confusing to someone from an OOP background if the analogy is taken too literally.
Or put differently, that is why `obj` apears twice in the `call` lambda.